# UINib not found when iOS target is 3.1.3

Tags: iphone

Hi
I am using SDK 4.1 to build an iPhone app and I set the target OS to 3.1.3.
When I install the app on devices running iOS4.1. everything goes smoothly. 
When I try to run the app on devices running 3.1.3 I get the stacktrace below.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UINib
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/BDD67A1E-9B40-43E7-A012-7D92036B2E24/ThisIsMy.app/ThisIsMy
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
 in /var/mobile/Applications/BDD67A1E-9B40-43E7-A012-7D92036B2E24/ThisIsMy.app/ThisIsMy
```

My guess is that it's because UINib was only added to the SDK in 4.0.

What I would like to know is how you mitigate this problem. What should I do to support 3.1.3?

Cheers..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you need to change the framework reference to a [weak link (aka "optional")](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeProjectManagement/130-Files_in_Projects/project_files.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002666-SW4). Then use the techniques described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH9-SW3) to test that a class exists before calling your code that uses it.

Comment: Gah! What AWrightIV says. (I tried to delete this answer but couldn't.) I didn't notice that the framework involved was UIKit. You *definitely* do not want to weakly link UIKit.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you **not** weakly link UIKit. This may hide future linker issues and result in crashes. I'm also simply not comfortable with telling the linker that UIKit is optional when it plainly isn't. Big hack.

Instead, initialize and call UIPopoverController indirectly using NSClassFromString:

```
Class popover = NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController");
if (nil != popover)
{
    self.myPopover = [[popover alloc] initWithContentViewController:myContent];
}
```

If you still have linker errors, you may need to call UIPopoverController's messages using NSSelectorFromString:

```
Class popover = NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController");
if (nil != popover)
{
    SEL myInit = NSSelectorFromString(@"initWithContentViewController:");
    self.myPopover = [[popover alloc] performSelector:myInit withObject:myContent];
}
```

For portability, I recommend writing a proxy object to handle these implementation details.